# Cannot link CSS to HTML

Tags: html, css

Please help to check why I cannot link `club.css` to `index.html`.

index.html (Please note: I have to use the direct local path as the `CSS` link, or it will show that "some content has been disabled in this document.")

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>The California Corgi Dog Club</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\leeson\Desktop\CS651 Web Systems\assignment\assignmentfall2021-Rijutady\clubProject\club.css" />
</head>
```

**club.css** (*Please note that the css file is under Encoding utf-8*)

```
h1 {
    background-color: skyblue
}
```

Comment: What are you using to access the HTML document? Are you just opening it directly or through a webserver (XAMPP, WAMP, etc.)?

Comment: have you copied the correct path..? Recheck the path..

Comment: no ,

it will be <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="club.css" />

if its under the clubproject

Answer (score 1):

### The Simple Answer

Using a relative path should resolve your issue for most situations.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./club.css"/>
```

### The Alternative

You could also include the CSS directly into the HTML document, however this is not always ideal or recommended. [Here's an article on that.](https://basarat.medium.com/inline-styles-are-bad-d0a3004c6b23)

```html
<style>
  h1 {
    background-color: skyblue
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

@NullPointDev's answer is correct. Use `Relative path` to your projects. It will make your work easier without errors. I just put some additional information for make your project easier.

- If both HTML and CSS files in same directory, You can link your CSS like this,

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="club.css"/>
```

- If the CSS file is located in another directory in the directory which the HTML file located, you can use this method.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="name_of_the_subdirectory/club.css"/>
```

- If the CSS file located in out of the directory which the HTML file located, Use `../` to go back.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../club.css"/>
```

---

[Read this Article for more info. Relative Path | W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp)

Now you know all the basics of `Relative path`. Wish you all the best.

Comment: Thanks for covering those extra cases, I didn't really think to mention them because of the way that the original question's example referenced the CSS's path, but this is definitely quite a bit more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

no ,

it will be `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="club.css" />`

if its under the clubproject

Answer (score 0):

The solution code for your question is:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type ="text/css" href = "club.css">`

Your mistake : You have written the complete folder path instead of relative file path.

Advice: Have a look to the below link to clear concept.
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Answer (score -1):

I prefer simple solution which is using relative path.

club.css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=".\club.css" />
```

Where is the [problem](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp):

> URLs cannot contain spaces